# sem_timedwait() does not work for the remote machine

Tags: c++, linux, posix, semaphore, errno

I have written a C++ program for thread synchronization. The program works for my computer, for which the operating system is Ubuntu 16.04. While running the program on the remote machine with Ubuntu 18.04, a different behaviour arise. I am simply using `sem_timedwait()` function of Linux ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_timedwait))  to cause timeout if some signals do not arrive on time. Here tfoundry() is called by posix-threads and it shall wait for signals `sem1` and `sem2` to continue its execution. After 5 seconds, even if one of the signals is not received, the thread must stop running.

```
struct Foundry{
    sem_t sem1;
    sem_t sem2;
    const struct timespec* abs_timeout;
    struct timeval currentTime;
    struct timespec ts;
};


void* tfoundry(void* f){
    Foundry* foundry = (Foundry*) f;
    sem_init(&(foundry->sem1), 0, 0);
    sem_init(&(foundry->sem2), 0, 0);
    foundry->abs_timeout = &(foundry->ts);
    gettimeofday(&(foundry->currentTime),NULL);
    // 5 sec for timeout
    foundry->ts.tv_sec = foundry->currentTime.tv_sec + 5; 
    if (sem_timedwait(&(foundry->sem1),foundry->abs_timeout) != 0) 
        exit(-1);

    if (sem_timedwait(&(foundry->sem2),foundry->abs_timeout) != 0) 
        exit(-1);
}
```

In my computer, this thread waits for 5 seconds and if not two signals have arrived, it simply exits. But on the remote machine it suddenly exits without waiting 5 seconds. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: whats the return value from sem_init?

Comment: @g19fanatic Both operations return 0

Comment: Does `sem_timedwait()` return -1? If so, what's `errno`? First guess: It's `EINVAL` because you don't properly initialize that `ts` member of the Foundry struct wherever you allocate/declare it. (And why don't you just pass that address instead of storing it in another member first?)

Comment: @Shawn You are right! Now, I initialized `ts` properly and it works. Thank you very much.